# What is the difference between the instructions STI, RET and IRET in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

So in assembly, STI enables interrupts, and RET takes a number from the stack and puts it in the IP and resumes execution at instruction [IP]. IRET does both of these, right? Then why shouldn't I just be able to use STI and RET instead? Or can I always just use IRET?

Comment: what instruction set?

Comment: I assume you're talking about the x86 processor. You should add that tag. Lots of instructions and their addressing modes can be implemented as combinations of others. The architects saw some advantage in adding such a complex instruction (size, speed, atomicity, etc.), so they did it. That said, IRET also restores the flags register, which I don't believe a simple RET does. So your 2-instruction sequence isn't equivalent. Moreover, in x86 modes other than real, IRET has additional memory management-related functions.

Comment: You don't want an interrupt to arrive between the STI and RET.

Comment: [`iret`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/iret:iretd) pops FLAGS *after* popping CS:IP off the stack; that would be inconvenient to emulate.  It's not equivalent to a `ret far`

Comment: When there is a privilege reduction (a numerical increate in CPL), the iret instruction will also pull an ss,sp pair off the stack.   Furthermore, if the descriptor in the to be loaded cs is a task descriptor, the machine will load all of the user registers, + ldt, and in 32bit mode cr3 + ddr[0-3] as well.   That is even less convenient to emulate :)

Comment: @Raymond, STI delays enabling interrupts for one instruction after the STI instruction, so that can’t happen.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under a [CC BY-SA license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Answer (score 6):

`iret` is complex - its behavior depends on many things (CPU mode, return info, etc) and in some cases it might do a full hardware task switch (changing every general purpose register and CR3/the virtual address space).

The simplest possible `iret` will load CS, IP/EIP/RIP and FLAGS/EFLAGS from the stack; but typically it also loads SS and SP/ESP/RSP too; and all segment register loads (CS, SS) cause GDT or LDT lookups and protection checks (which add overhead).

Also note that loading FLAGS/EFLAGS restores its previous value. If mask-able interrupts are disabled before the interrupt handler is started (which is possible for software interrupts and exceptions) then the FLAGS/EFLAGS saved on the stack will have "interrupt flag clear" and the `IRET` will restore "interrupt flag clear" and will not cause "interrupt flag set".

`ret` only loads IP/EIP/RIP from the stack. It doesn't load CS or FLAGS/EFLAGS.

`sti` doesn't load FLAGS/EFLAGS and only sets one bit, and this includes not restoring all of the other flags (e.g. carry, overflow, ...). This can be an extremely important difference (e.g. you don't want IRQs to trash arithmetic flags at unknown/random times and cause unpredictable failures everywhere).

This means that `sti` then `ret` is very different to (the simplest possible) `IRET` - it does a lot less and the behavior (involving FLAGS/EFLAGS) is very different.

The closest sequence to emulate the behavior of `iret` would be `popf` (to restore FLAGS/EFLAGS to its previous value) and then `retf` (to load CS, and IP/EIP/RIP); and this may have the same complex behaviors (e.g. may or may not cause privilege level change, may or may not cause hardware task switch).

However; even in this "as close as possible to IRET" case it's not the same, because the 2 separate instructions are separate - there's a risk that an IRQ will occur after the `popf` but before the `retf`.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the saved [E/R]FLAGS is *above* the saved CS:IP on the stack (unless I'm misreading the order of `pop()` in https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/iret:iretd Operation section), so you actually need to push a copy of it then, then `popf`, then `retf 8` (if that's even possible) to far ret and pop the saved RFLAGS.  Or copy the CS:IP upwards, collapsing the gap where the saved RFLAGS was.

Comment: And yeah, unlike STI, a `popf` that sets IF doesn't delay interrupts until after the *next* instruction.  You *could* work around that by extracting and clearing that bit from the saved RFLAGS and branching to STI/RETF or just doing RETF with interrupts still disabled.  Anyway, the TL:DR is that emulating even the simplest `iret` would be a lot more complicated.